# ampersand used in SET /A command in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, special-characters, ampersand

Could you please advice what using "&" or "^" in **SET** command means (I haven't found any explanation by using Google).

For example, following Windows batch code block

```
SET V_COMMAND=3
SET /A V_FLAG="%V_COMMAND%&2"
echo VFlag is: %V_FLAG%
```

produces:

```
VFlag is: 2
```

But I haven't any opinion about what command above does.

Also there is another case with "**^**":

```
SET V_COMMAND=3
SET /A V_FLAG="%V_COMMAND%^3"
echo VFlag is: %V_FLAG%
```

For this case output is:

```
VFlag is: 0
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the SET command? The documentation is available by entering `set /?` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `set /a`, the indicated characters are bitwise operators:

```
& = bitwise AND = 1 if both bits are 1
^ = bitwise XOR = 1 if only one of the two bits is 1
```

So if `a` is `10` (`1010` in binary) and `b` is 13 (`1101` in binary)

```
         1010              1010
         1101              1101
         ----              ----
         1000 = a & b      0111 = a ^ b
```

Or in your case with `3 dec = 11 bin` and `2 dec = 10 bin`

```
           11                11
           10                11
           --                --
           10 = 3&2 = 2      00 = 3^3 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are bitwise operators - `&` is bitwise AND, and `^` is bitwise XOR. These bitwise operators are only available with `SET /A`.